# Finding a point that is twice as distant from a point as it is from the origin

Tags: geometry

Hi I have a problem which requires me to find the point which is twice the distance from $(1,2)$ as it is from the origin.

My problem is that when i constructed the following formula $((x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2)^{1/2} =2(x^2 +y^2)^{1/2}$ and then squared it the resulting point would be 4 times away from the point as it is from the origin.

However when i used the square root of two instead of two i got the right answer. Why is this?

Reasoning it out the rhs of the formula indicates rhe distance not squared in the rhs if the lhs of the equation is squarerooted

Comment: This was mentioned in the comments to @Ravenex's answer, but there are several points that satisfy the criterion you give. Also, I don't understand how you get to the conclusion that "the point" you obtain through your equation is 4 times farther from $(1,2)$ than from the origin. What point did you find?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ApolloniusCircle.html

Answer (score 2):

I think I have guessed where you went wrong.

Let's call $P$ the point at coordinates $(1,2)$, $O$ the origin, and $M$ some point at coordinates $(x,y)$. What you started to do was express the condition $d(M,P)=2d(M,O)$ with the equation $\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2}=2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. 
This can be worked out into the equation of a circle:
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2}=2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}
&\iff x^2-2x+1+y^2-4y+4=4x^2+4y^2\\
&\iff x^2+\frac 23x+y^2+\frac 43y=\frac 53\\
&\iff \left(x+\frac 13\right)^2 +\left(y+\frac 23\right)^2=\left(\frac 23\sqrt 5\right)^2
\end{align*}
We thus obtain that $M$ must belong to the circle centered at point $(-\frac 13,-\frac 23)$ with radius $\frac 23\sqrt 5$.

I suspect that instead of interpreting the above equations as constraints that $x,y$ must satisfy, you directly took the center of the circle as the "solution" of your equation. In which case, the distance between
point $C(-\frac 13,-\frac 23)$ and point $P$ is $4\frac{\sqrt{5}}3$, and the distance between $C$ and $O$ is $\frac{\sqrt 5}3$. So you would get to the (wrong) conclusion that "the" solution to the equation gives you a point whose distance to $P$ is $4$ times its distance to $O$.

What you said about taking $\sqrt 2$ instead of $2$ also comforts me in my interpretation. If you have a look at $d(M,P)=\sqrt 2d(M,O)$, we instead obtain
$$
\left( x+1\right)^2+\left( y+2\right)^2=10
$$
If, again, we directly take the center of the circle, $C_2(-1,-2)$, we get
$d(C_2,P)=2\sqrt 5$ and $d(C_2,O)=\sqrt 5$. So you would get the (wrong) conclusion that the equation gives you "the right" answer.

On a side note, we could verify that $C_2$ lies on the circle of solutions.

Anyway, assuming my guess is right, what the equation means is that you need a point $(x,y)$ ***such that***
$(x+1/3)^2+(y+2/3)^2=20/9$.
The equation does **NOT** mean that
that "$x=-1/3$" and "$y=-2/3$".

Answer (score 1):

Let $Q$ be the point $(1,2)$ and let $O = (0,0)$. Then we seek the set of all points $P$ such that

\begin{align}
  PQ &= 2PO \\
  |P-Q| &= 2|P| \\
  |P-Q|^2 &= 4|P|^2 \\
  (P-Q)\circ(P-Q) &= 4P\circ P \\
  P \circ P - 2P \circ Q + Q \circ Q &= 4 P \circ P \\
  3P \circ P + 2 P \circ Q - Q \circ Q &= 0 \\
  (3P - Q) \circ (P+Q) &= 0 \\
  \left(P - \dfrac 13 Q \right) \circ (P+Q) &= 0
\end{align}

In words, the segment with endpoints at $P$ and $\dfrac 13 Q$ is perpendicular to the segment with endpoints at $P$ and $-Q$; that is 
$$\text{$\triangle \left(\dfrac 13Q\right)(P)(-Q)$ is a right triangle.}$$

[image]

This describes a circle with a diameter having endpoints at $\dfrac 13 Q$ and at $-Q$.
If $Q = (1,2)$, then its center is at $C = -\dfrac 13 Q = \left(-\dfrac 13, -\dfrac 23 \right)$ and its radius is $r = \left| \dfrac 23Q \right| = \dfrac 23 \sqrt 5$.

So the equation of the circle is

$$\left(x + \dfrac 13 \right)^2 + \left(y + \dfrac 23 \right)^2 = \dfrac{20}{9}$$

Answer (score 0):

Logically the point twice the distance from (1,2) as it is to the origin would be the point 1/3 of the way between. Making is (1/3,2/3).

Distance to origin: $A = \sqrt{\mathrm{\frac13}^2+\mathrm{\frac23}^2} = \sqrt{\frac59}$

Distance to (1,2): $B = \sqrt{\mathrm{\frac23}^2+\mathrm{\frac43}^2} = \sqrt{\frac{20}9}$

2A = B: 
$2(\sqrt{\frac59}) = \sqrt{\frac{20}9} => 4(\frac59) = \frac{20}9 => \frac{20}9 = \frac{20}9$

[image]

This shows how the point at $(\frac13,\frac23)$ satisfys the criteria, but so does the point $(1,0)$. It also shows the circle that would be constructed if you plotted the equation of the points.

Comment: Could you please clarify?

Comment: You've been on this site long enough to know that you should use mathjax to format mathematics. Also: as a matter of style, your last equation starts by assuming what you want to prove and concluding that $20/9 = 20/9$. Although it's clear what you mean - you're checking that the distances you found are in the right ratio - the logic is backwards. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: To be thorough there is an infinite number of point that meet your criteria, they form a circle around the origin.

Given your criteria, the point can be said to be 1 unit from the origin and two units from (1,2). The simplest point that the meets this is if the unit is defined as 1/3 the distance between the origin and (1,2).

Comment: @EthanBolker I apologize, my mathjax fluency is poor. So I try to avoid it, I will edit the answer to use it properly.

Comment: Your mathjax fluency will get better as you use it. While you are editing I think you should show the algebra that gives the whole circle as the set of all the points. Then the one you found first is on the line joining the original points given. There's another one on that line on the far side of the circle.

Comment: The circle of solution isn't centered at the origin I think? I'd like to see the complete development of your answer.

Comment: @N.Bach You are correct... I got a bit ahead of myself. The circle is centered at (-1/3,-2/3).